# Remove section number but display the number in table of contents in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I am new to LateX. I know how to remove the section number by using `\section*{heading}` instead of `\section{heading}`.
But when I display the section heading in the Table of Contents , it does not print  the section number. I want the section number to be displayed before "Introduction to Project" and "Introduction to company" in the Table of Contents shown below.

[image: Table of content]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`titlesec`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package is very useful to modify your chapter and section titles. An important command is `\titleformat`, which is described on page 4 of the manual. The command looks like this:

```
\titleformat{⟨command⟩}[⟨shape⟩]{⟨format⟩}{⟨label⟩}{⟨sep⟩}{⟨before-code⟩}[⟨after-code⟩]
```

here, we want to change the `\section` command, i.e. `<command>` is `\section`.
The `<shape>` setting is optional - we'll just leave the default value. In `<format>`, we define how the title shall be formatted. The default for `\section` is `\normalfont\Large\bfseries`, so we'll set it to that. If you want to change the appearance, you can do that here. Now, the interesting part: the `<label>` is the section number - we don't want to print it, so we'll lave that field empty. The `<sep>` is the separation between label and title, which should be zero if we don't have a label. Finally, with `<before-code>` and `<after-code>` we can add any code which should be run before or after printing the title. We don't need that either. So, our command is:

```
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}
```

Here, a demonstration of that:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction to Company}
This is the company.

\section{Introduction to Project}
My project is very nice.

\end{document}
```

[image: resulting document]